# Partial include paths in mustache.js

Tags: javascript, templating, mustache

I am trying to include a partial inside my template from within a directory.

This works:

```
{{>header}}
```

This doesn't:

```
{{>inc/header}}

{{>../header}}
```

Any location other than a sibling doesn't seem to be picked up. Is this normal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`header`, `inc/header`, and `../header` are just names of keys in the partials object passed in at rendering time that have values of the partial text

```
var tmpl = "{{>header}} {{>inc/header}} {{>../header}}",
    data = {},
partials = {
  header : "<header>example</header>",
  'inc/header' : "<header>xmpl</header>",
  '../header' : "whatever"
},
html = Mustache.render(tmpl, data, partials);

document.write(html);
```

See here on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/maxbeatty/CWKHe/